# How to automatically add participants? Vidyo

Tags: android, webrtc, vidyo

I have been trying to develop a video calling application using Vidyo SDK, after reading a lot from their documentation and samples and luckily i was able to make a working application. But on the go am facing some issues. Any kind of help or suggestions will be totally appreciated.

1. I know for vidyo conferencing Token is to be kept constant. But my doubt is when i am generating a token, lets say an expiry time of 10 minutes and initiated a call. Will the call be disconnected after 10 minutes? I know user cannot use the token after the expiry time.
2. Suppose there are two admin users and 10 child users for each, i have added one application under Vidyo dashboard. So my second question is, two admin users are initiating two separate call, first admin user create a token with 10 minutes expiry and at the same time the second admin created another token against the same developer key and app id, so will the token created by first admin will still be alive? Or will it get overwritten by the token generated by the second admin user?
3. Last and main question (needs suggestions and help), how to automatically add participants, i have a table with list of users registered to my application, and before starting a call, i am selecting a list of participants to get notified about the call (Am thinking like implementing push notifications, but is there any other options available within the Vidyo SDK, else is there any better approach).

Will totally appreciate all helps and suggestions.
Thanks in advance

*PS: Feel free to edit the question title.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those questions are pretty common when we're starting with Vidyo.io. Here are some insights on them:

1. If a token expires after the user initiated a call he/she won't be
   disconnect from any ongoing conference. The user will not be able to
   join another call before renewing the token, though. This is explained in the [Generate a token](https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/115003127747-Generate-a-Token) section of the docs.
2. The short answer is: the second token will not invalidate the first
   token. Long answer: the users registered in vidyo.io dashboard have
   absolutely no relation with your videoconference users. You only
   need one admin user to get your developer ID to inject in your
   application, and from there you have to manage who will join or
   leave any conference any point in time. You can have any amount of
   users in you app, generating any amount of tokens, joining any
   amount of conferences independently.
3. In vidyo.io you're responsible for the entire workflow of your users
   joining or leaving conferences, so the push notifications for a
   given user to join a call is a good idea. Vidyo.io's API is totally
   unaware of your implementation details, so there is no API to
   "invite" a user to a conference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) For the second point am still confused a bit, As far i understood, the tokens are not related against a developer key, so each token is independent and also will not overwrite others, right? Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You're partially right: the tokens are composed of the developer key, among other things, but one token has absolutely no relation to the other. A token is just an encrypted composition of developer key, application ID, username and expiration. It is worth mentioning that "username" is just some random string you define, that has no relation with your admin or any other user registered in vidyo.io developer portal.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot. :) Please do update the answer once you find out the valuable links for future readers also.